# Exec stored procedure with two string parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I wrote this procedure and defined two strings as parameters for it :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spo_SelectTable1sDynamic]
    @WhereCondition nvarchar(500),
    @OrderByExpression nvarchar(250) = NULL
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(3250)

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT
                    [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4]
                FROM
                    [dbo].[Table1]
                WHERE
               ' + @WhereCondition

    IF @OrderByExpression IS NOT NULL AND LEN(@OrderByExpression) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + 'ORDER BY ' + @OrderByExpression
    END

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

I should pass two strings for `@whereconditio` and `@OrderByExpression` parameters.

How can I execute this stored procedure? I use this code but get an error:

```
EXECUTE spo_SelectTable1sDynamic N'col1='book'' , N'col1 '
```

Comment: **[Possible SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)** Especially `@wherecondtition` passed entirely as string

Comment: OK  ................

Comment: What is bunch of parameters?

Comment: You mean is that I must pass value only for sp  no where condition . Is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your code is very vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) attack.

Second [SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE @condition](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Condition) is curse:

> If you are considering to write the procedure
>
> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE search_sp @condition varchar(8000) AS    
> SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE @condition
> ```
>
> **Just forget it. If you are doing this, you have not completed the
>   transition to use stored procedure and you are still assembling your
>   SQL code in the client.**

Possible solution is to use *Dynamic Search Conditions* and avoid dynamic-SQL at all:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spo_SelectTable1sDynamic]
    @col1 NVARCHAR(1000),   -- depending on business cases
    @col2 INT ...,
    @sortColumn SYSNAME
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT ....
  FROM table ...
  WHERE (col1 = @col1 OR @col1 IS NULL)
    AND (col2 = @col2 OR @col2 IS NULL) ...
  ORDER BY
     CASE @sortColumn
          WHEN 'col1' THEN col1 
          WHEN 'col2' THEN col2
          ...
     END
END
```

User can call it as:

```
EXEC [dbo].[spo_SelectTable1sDynamic] @col1 = 'aaa'
EXEC [dbo].[spo_SelectTable1sDynamic] @col2 = 10
EXEC [dbo].[spo_SelectTable1sDynamic] @col1 = 'bbb', @col2 = 16
-- or even
EXEC [dbo].[spo_SelectTable1sDynamic
-- to get all possible rows without any filter
```